# How to remove <div> and <br> using Cheerio js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have the following html that I like to parse through Cheerios.

```
    var $ = cheerio.load('<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;"><div>This works well.</div><div><br clear="none"/></div><div>So I have been doing this for several hours. How come the space does not split? Thinking that this could be an issue.</div><div>Testing next paragraph.</div><div><br clear="none"/></div><div>Im testing with another post. This post should work.</div><div><br clear="none"/></div><h1>This is for test server.</h1></body></html>', {
    normalizeWhitespace: true,
});

// trying to parse the html
// the goals are to 
// 1. remove all the 'div'
// 2. clean up <br clear="none"/> into <br>
// 3. Have all the new 'empty' element added with 'p'

var testData = $('div').map(function(i, elem) {
    var test = $(elem)
    if ($(elem).has('br')) {
        console.log('spaceme');
        var test2 = $(elem).removeAttr('br');
    } else {
        var test2 = $(elem).removeAttr('div').add('p');
    }
    console.log(i +' '+ test2.html());
    return test2.html()
})

res.send(test2.html())
```

My end goals are to try and parse the html

- remove all the div
- clean up `<br clear="none"/>` and change into `<br>`
- and finally have all the empty 'element' (those sentences with 'div') remove to be added with 'p' sentence '/p'

I try to start with a smaller goal in the above code I have written. I tried to remove all the 'div' (it is a success) but I'm unable to to find the 'br. I been trying out for days and have no head way.

So I'm writing here to seek some help and hints on how can I get to my end goal.

Thank you :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's easier than it looks, first you iterate over all the DIV's

```
$('div').each(function() { ...
```

and for each div, you check if it has a `<br>` tag

```
$(this).find('br').length
```

if it does, you remove the attribute

```
$(this).find('br').removeAttr('clear');
```

if not you create a P with the same content

```
var p = $('<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>');
```

and then just replace the DIV with the P

```
$(this).replaceWith(p);
```

and output

```
res.send($.html());
```

All together it's

```
$('div').each(function() {
    if ( $(this).find('br').length ) {
        $(this).find('br').removeAttr('clear');
    } else {
        var p = $('<p>' + $(this).html() + '</p>');
        $(this).replaceWith(p);
    }
});

res.send($.html());
```

Comment: Hi @adeneo 

Thank you so much!. 
Your solutions works great. How would you suggest if I would only like to add the <p>sentence</p> for the sentences only while the <br> leave it as it is after removing the 'clear'.

attached an image link to hopefully make my question clearer :D
[image](http://note.io/1N4YG7x)

Comment: @bosslee - I'm not quite sure what you mean ?

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to add
`<p>only to the sentences</p>' but not the object with 
'<br>'

From your code, I try to come up with the following.
![image here](http://note.io/1GClUxg)

I put it in the image because when I try to paste code in the comment it is in a mess.

Thank you so much.

Comment: So you want to keep the DIV if it has a BR, and just remove the attribute?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! without your help. I would not be able to figure out the code. I have manage to get out desire outcome. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @adeneo
May I seek your expertise on one more question. :D
For the last statement / the last object in the html 
> This is for test server. 

I like to append a unique html to it  <p>yeah! done</p>
so it might end up like <p>This is for test server.</p><p>yeah! done</p>

Do you have a hint for me on finding the last object and appending it with the correct text :D Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you want to do this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ko5dcsko/1/**, but note that the element with the text "This is for test server" is a H1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71989/discussion-between-bosslee-and-adeneo).

Comment: super work.. i would say.. i thought initially it wont work.. later from urs i came to know its possible. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to remove an attribute you want to remove the tag and so you want to switch `removeAttr` to `remove`, like so:

```
var testData = $('div').map(function(i, elem) {
    var test = $(elem)
    if ($(elem).has('br')) {
        console.log('spaceme');
        var test2 = $(elem).remove('br');
    } else {
        var test2 = $(elem).remove('div').add('p');
    }
    console.log(i +' '+ test2.html());
    return test2.html()
})
```